# wso2 spring security saml stateless integration

Tags: spring, wso2, saml, spring-saml

I am using Wso2 identity server 5.11.0 as IDP and Spring SAML for SAML integration. But after the authentication the spring SAML stores jsession-id in the client browser using which further communication happens. So, how can we make the integration stateless instead of storing session at service provide(spring security).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to avoid creating a session cookie on client-side.

Stateless web applications are nearly impossible if you need to authenticate the users.

If you are not going to keep track of the user's session on the client-side, you will have to talk to the identity provider each and every time to make sure the user is authenticated which will make the user experience worse.

One other alternative is to append a user session id to each and every request made from the browser, so the user session will be identified by that request parameter instead of a session cookie.

For single-page applications, the backend can be stateless. Still, the UI is keeping a session on the browser.